# how to write regular expression in python to find all Words with two consonants next to each other

Tags: python, regex

I tried this code but does not work

```py
string2 = "eat black  eat eaten  name 1234 stop  double " //sample of string
result62 = re.findall(r'\b\w+[^ 0-9][^ aeiouAEIOU]{2}\b', string2)
print(result62)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
string2 = "eat black  eat eaten  name 1234 stop  double "
result62 = re.findall(r'\b(?=[a-z]*(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){2})[a-z]*\b', string2)
print(result62)
```

prints:

```
['black', 'stop', 'double']
```

Comment: The use of a lookahead makes this regex significantly less efficient (~3x more steps) than a simple character class.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following regex:

```
\b[a-z]*[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{2}[a-z]*\b
```

This looks for a

- word break `\b`
- some number of letters `[a-z]*`
- 2 consonants `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{2}`
- some number of letters `[a-z]*`
- a word break

I would look for two consonants specifically to avoid having to worry about matching (for example) `fuel.`

In python:

```
string2 = "eat black  eat eaten  name 1234 stop  double fuel."
result62 = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]*[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{2}[a-z]*\b', string2, re.I)
```

Use the `re.I` flag to avoid having to specify both upper and lower case letters in the character classes.

Result (for your data):

```
['black', 'stop', 'double']
```

Comment: You could shorten the character class for "2 consonants" by using excluding all non-word and also all vowels: `\b[a-z]*[^aeiou\W]{2}[a-z]*\b`

Comment: @leoshThat matches for example `regex11`, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b\w*(?:(?![aeiou0-9])\w){2}\w*\b
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/36VzAk/1

Comment: The use of a lookahead makes this regex significantly less efficient (~3x more steps) than a simple character class.

Comment: @Nick yes was lazy to design to this `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to retrieve the whole words having two consonants next to each other, and ignoring digits, you could use this regex `(\w*[^aeiou\d\s]{2,}\w*)`.

- `\w*` will look for any word character, zero or more times
- `[^aeiou\d\s]{2,}` will look for at least two consecutive consonants (any non-digit, non-whitespace, non-vowels characters)
- `\w*` will again look for any word character, zero or more times

```py
import re

my_string = "eat black eat eaten  name 1234 stop double"
my_re = re.compile(r"(\w*[^aeiou\d\s]{2,}\w*)", re.I)

matches = my_re.findall(my_string)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Outputs

```
black
stop
double
```